# Song in episode 13 when Sakuta and Mai were on a late-night date

Tags: music, rascal-does-not-dream-of-bunny-girl

In episode 13 of *Rascal Does Not Dream of Bunny Girl Senpai*, when Sakuta and Mai were on a late-night date towards the end of the episode, piano music is played. Here is the [YouTube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=77g6GN91XW0&t=42s).

What is that song?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be [青春ブタ野郎](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IBV9cAQuDA4&list=PLs2VrLLjL1aiYbKa1eLc6ixpOF9e9Xg75) (*Seishun Buta Yarou*). The BGM in the scene is rather faint but the piano melody line matches up. This is the first track on [the OST release](https://vgmdb.net/album/80667) and clearly takes its name from the title of the series itself.

Comment: The link to the YouTube soundtrack seems to be broken.